# K-means iterated for same data for 10 times

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, k-means

I am a fresher to R. Trying to evaluate if I can get an optimization of K-means (using R) by iteratively calling the k-means routine for same dataset and same value for K (i.e. k=3 in my case) of 10/15 times and see if if can give me good results. I see the clustering changes at every call, even the total sum of squares and withinss starts changing but not sure how to halt at the best situation.

Can anyone guide me?

code:

```
run_kmeans <- function(xtimes)
{

  for (x in 1:xtimes) 
    {
    kmeans_results <- kmeans(filtered_data, 3) 
    print(kmeans_results["totss"]) 
    print(kmeans_results["tot.withinss"])
  }   
  return(kmeans_results)
}
kmeans_results = run_kmeans(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question because this is not the usual way of selecting the best partition (elbow method, silhouette method, etc.)

Let's say you want to find the kmeans partition that minimizes your  within-cluster sum of squares.

Let's take the example from `?kmeans`

```
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
```

You could write that to run repetitively kmeans:

```r
xtimes <- 10
kmeans <- lapply(seq_len(xtimes), function(i){
  kmeans_results <- kmeans(x, 3)
})
```

`lapply` is always preferrable to `for`. You output a list. To extract withinss and see which one is minimal:

```r
perf <- sapply(kmeans, function(d) as.numeric(d["tot.withinss"]))
which.min(perf)
```

However, unless I misunderstood your objective, this is a strange way to select the most performing partition. Usually, this is the number of clusters that is evaluated ; not different partititons produced with the same sample data and the same number of clusters.

## Edit from your comment

Ok, so you want to find the combination of columns that give you the best performance. I give you an example below where every two by two combinations of three variables is tested. You could generalize a little bit (but the number of combinations possible with 8 variables is very big, you should have a routine to reduce the number of tested combinations)

```r
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 3),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 3)
)
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y","z")

combinations <- combn(colnames(x), 2, simplify = FALSE)
kmeans <- lapply(combinations, function(i){
  kmeans_results <- kmeans(x[,i], 3)
})

perf <- sapply(kmeans, function(d) as.numeric(d["tot.withinss"]))
which.min(perf)
```

Comment: I'll elaborate my objective to make more sense. You are right that my way is not the conventional one.  i have a diabetes population which I want to cluster in 3 groups and there are 8 data attributes which I can play with, so I am trying to see which combination gives the best results in terms of division of risk (low, moderate, high). It is done see if k-means can identify the risk groups. I am aware of elbow and silhouette, but here I know a bit of what the end results should be, and trying to understand if I can tweak it towards the goal.

Comment: Thanks, from your experience do you feel that k-means works best with more attributes (columns) or smaller set of attributes? Like should I go incremental or decremental for optimizating the solution for finding the minimum "withinss". Is there any other variable of k-means that I should also be accounting for so as to optimize (like sum of errors etc.)

Comment: I would start from little and incrementally add some variables. Otherwise you might overfit. You should try some kind of [stepwise procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression) that would make you the job easier. For your performance criterion, don't forget that the more you add variable, the better your fit will be. To avoid overfitting, you should maybe look at the incremental decrease of your `withinss`